# how can I use JS to Remove a tag off when a Option is selected in a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating an artist's site. There is a contact form on the site, and I am trying to create a JS script to remove the hidden class I put on the commission rules, so it can be visible when the Commission option is selected on the form. I'm new to JS, but From the documentation I've read HTMLOptionElement type seems to be the best way to do this in vanilla JS. Here is the form, and my approximations of trying to remove the element:

```
                <form action="action_page.php" id="contactform" method="post" action="FormToEmail.php">
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />   
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" />
                        <select id="reason" name="contact-reason">
                            <option value="None" selected disabled hidden>Reason for contact</option>
                            <option value="Brand">Brand</option>
                            <option id="Comission"value="Comission">Commission</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                      </select>
                      <a class="invis hidden center" href=""> Commission rules</a>
                    <textarea name="contact-message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment"> </textarea>    
                    <input type="submit" class="button form-buttion" value="SUBMIT"/>
                </form>
```

I've also tried selecting by ID, by tags, and other selectors. The JS is here.

```
var action = document.HTMLOptionElement("Commission")
if(action == true){
  element.classList.remove("invis");
}
```

Comment: You want to now if the `<option>` with `id="commission"` is selected so you can remove a class from the `<a>` with `class="invis"` on it? Is that the problem?

Comment: On another not, you spell "commission" in two different ways in your files.. Makes sure you properly call the class names!

Answer (score 0):

document.HTMLOptionElement is not a function. The correct way to check if an option is selected is:

```
document.getElementById('reason').value === "Commision";
```

You can also remove the id from the option element.

So:

```
if(document.getElementById('reason').value === "Commision"){
   element.classList.remove("invis");
}
```